# Will my GoPro 5 Hero Black work with Verbatim Premium SDHC Class 10

Tags: memory-card, gopro, performance

I've just bought a new Go Pro Hero 5 Black and a couple of accessories , since I've already spent a lot , was thinking of getting a cheaper memory card.

The Verbatim Premium SDHC Class 10  is cheaper compared to sandisk or samsung memory cards of the same specs. 
https://www.harveynorman.com.au/verbatim-premium-sdhc-32gb-uhs-i-class-10-memory-card.html 
As you can see this one is $18 compared to the sandisk one which is $32.

**My question is will this card perform as well as the sandisk ones ? I coudn't find any info on the anywhere.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be suitable.  All current GoPros say they require a minimum of class 10, which this card is.

All the recommended cards for the Hero5 Black are UHS-1, which your chosen SD card is.  UHS-1 is a similar performance level to class 10 but is more strict so it is considered a step above class 10 (UHS-1 cards are also class 10, but not all class 10 cards are also UHS-1).

See also https://gopro.com/help/articles/Block/microSD-Card-Considerations

As to the the longevity/reliability of the card, I can't comment.  Verbatim were a good quality brand in floppy disks, and then in recordable optical discs, but I don't have much experience with them in flash media.  I do think that the hype over Sandisk reliability is overblown.

Comment: " I do think that the hype over Sandisk reliability is overblown." - Yes even I think so

Comment: FWIW I'm Australian too and I've seen the Lexar "633x" cards in places like Woolworths and Target and those are on the recommended list (not that I think you need to only choose cards from the recommended list).

Comment: Cool , ya I've seen those, just find them too expensive